# Deleting contents of text file

Tags: swift, read-write

I'm reading and writing to a text file. There is an instance where I want to delete the contents of the file (but not the file) as a kind of reset. How can I do this?

```
if ((dirs) != nil) {
    var dir = dirs![0]; //documents directory

    let path = dir.stringByAppendingPathComponent("UserInfo.txt");
    println(path)
    let text = "Rondom Text"

    //writing
    text.writeToFile(path, atomically: false, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)

    //reading
    let text2 = String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)

    println(text2)
```

Comment: Did you get any error with your code?

Comment: Nothing wrong with the above code. I would just like to know how to delete the contents of the file... i.e. here I'm writing to the file and then the user presses reset, so the file becomes empty.

Comment: `"".writeToFile(path, atomically: false, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)` The file will have cleared.

Comment: If that solved your issue, please accept my answer :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simply write an empty string to the file like this:

```
let text = ""
text.writeToFile(path, atomically: false, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
```

Answer (score 9):

If you set up an `NSFileHandle`, you can use [`-truncateFileAtOffset:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileHandle_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileHandle/truncateFileAtOffset:), passing 0 for the offset.

Or, as pointed out in comments, you can simply write an empty string or data to the file.

Or you can use some kind of data structure / database that does not require you to manually truncate files :)

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 3.x**

```
let text = ""
do {
     try text.write(toFile: fileBundlePath, atomically: false, encoding: .utf8)
} catch {
     print(error)
}
```

**Swift 4.x**

```
let text = ""
do {
     try text.write(to: filePath, atomically: false, encoding: .utf8)
   } catch {
     print(error)
   }
```